# Why malloc assigns unknown digits in the string?

Tags: c, string

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){
    int temptn;
    char *ticno, temptn2[10];
    ticno = (char*)malloc(100);

    printf("%s", ticno);
    for (int i=0; i < 6; i++){
        temptn = i;
        sprintf(temptn2, "%d", temptn);
        strcat(ticno, temptn2);
    }
    printf("\n%s", ticno);
   // prints &┐012345
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve the problem of getting unknown characters in the string after using malloc on the char *ticno?

Comment: You just allocated some memory, but it isn't cleared for you.

Comment: `malloc` does not assign any values. The values you observe are simply whatever happened to be in memory in the allocated bytes.

Comment: What did you expect?

Comment: Use calloc instead, it will initialize allocated memory to 0

Answer (score 3):

`malloc()` just allocates memory, it doesn't zero it for you, so there's likely to be arbitrary garbage in there.

You can do

```
ticno = (char*)malloc(100);
memset(ticno, 0, 100);
```

to zero those 100 bytes, or use [`calloc`, which does zero the memory](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc):

```
ticno = (char*)calloc(100, 1);
```